# I am comparing charged hours from 2 tables but the query takes forever to run, is there a way to quicken the process?

Tags: sql-server

This query takes a long time to run, basically trying to group hours by week and 2 other fields and see if the hours match

```
select sum(t1.chargedhours) as Hours, sum(t2.Charged_Hrs),t1.BU, t1.Competency, DATEPART(WK,t1.PeriodEndDate) as Week 
from rpt_engutilizationavailability as t1
left join
RPT_UtilizationAvailability as t2 
 on t1.bu=t2.bu
and t1.competency = t2.competency
where t1.EngTypeDescr = 'External Customer Project' or 
t1.EngTypeDescr = 'External Customer - Summarized' or  
t1.EngTypeDescr= 'PH - Chargeable, code not available' and 
t1.AvlFlg='n' and
t2.AvlFlg='n'
group by t1.BU,t1.Competency,t1.EngTypeDescr ,DATEPART(WK,t1.PeriodEndDate)
```

Comment: Is the answer correct, when you get it?

Comment: What are the estimated row counts for the 2 tables?  How many rows are being returned?  Do you have indexes set up?  Group by queries can take a while depending on the above questions.  You might be able to reduce the amount of data being returned from the `JOIN` by moving the AvlFlg criteria to the `JOIN`.  You should also probably use parentheses around the different criteria.

Comment: Also:  is there a `EngType` field you could select on rather than `EngTypeDescr`? Filtering and grouping by long strings takes a while.

Comment: Also: you might want to surround those `OR` clauses with parentheses. I suspect you're running into problems from logical operator precedence:  `A or B and C` is the same as `A or (B and C)` whereas I suspect you mean `(A or B) and C`.

Comment: I changed the clauses to include parenthesis in OR clauses but it still takes a long time to run the query. There arent that many records, few 100k i think

Answer (score 1):

Did you want your weeks to correspond between the tables?

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    e.wk AS Week ,
    e.BU,
    e.Competency,
    e.EngTypeDescr,
    SUM(e.chargedhours) AS Hours, 
    SUM(r.Charged_Hrs)
FROM 
    (SELECT
        chargedhours,
        EngTypeDescr,
        BU, 
        Competency,
        DATEPART(WK,PeriodEndDate) AS wk
    FROM
        rpt_engutilizationavailability
    WHERE
        EngTypeDescr IN ( 'External Customer Project', 'External Customer - Summarized','PH - Chargeable, code not available' ) AND 
        e.AvlFlg='n' ) AS e LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        BU, 
        Competency,
        DATEPART(WK,PeriodEndDate) AS wk
    FROM
        RPT_UtilizationAvailability
    WHERE
        AvlFlg='n') AS r  ON 
    e.bu=r.bu AND 
    e.competency = r.competency AND
    e.wk = r.wk
GROUP BY 
    e.wk,
    e.BU,
    e.Competency,
    e.EngTypeDescr
```